# MongoDB: Summing everything in a nested array

Tags: mongodb

I have the following collections in my database:

```
{
    "username" : "John",
    "shopping_cart" : {
        "coffee" : 2,
        "chocolate" : 3
      (...will have about 50 different products that can be added to the shopping cart)
    },
}
```

Is there a way to aggregate all items that a user had added in the shopping cart and get a total sum of the entire quantity of the cart? Something like this.

```
db.items.aggregate([
    {$group: {
        _id: null,
        prices: {$sum: "$all_items_in_shopping_cart}
    }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 different steps

1. First, convert your object to array

   $project: {
   shopingItems: {
   $objectToArray: "$shopping_cart"
   }
   }
2. Unwind your new element

   $unwind: {
   path: "$shopingItems"
   }
3. Group base on id to get the summation

   $group: {
   _id: "$_id",
   total: {
   $sum: "$shopingItems.v"
   }

Your final query be something like:

```js
db. items. aggregate[
    {    
    '$project': {
      'shopingItems': {
        '$objectToArray': '$shopping_cart'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$shopingItems'
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$_id', 
      'total': {
        '$sum': '$shopingItems.v'
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You an try,

- `$addFields` add new field `shopping_cart_sum`
- $reduce to input `shopping_cart` array after converting to array using `$objectsToArray`, set initialValue to zero, in to add value of object key and value of initialValue using `$add`

```
db.items.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      shopping_cart_sum: {
        $reduce: {
          input: { $objectToArray: "$shopping_cart" },
          initialValue: 0,
          in: { $add: ["$$this.v", "$$value"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9cfoAa78El-)